# How to create a zip file without entire directory structure

Tags: linux, zip

I am trying to create a zip file and want to preserve most of the directory structure, but not the rootdir as defined from the command line.   The command I'm using is:

```
zip -r out.zip /foo/bar/
```

I'd like it to recurse through bar and add all files with preserved directory structure (which it does). However I do not want 'foo' to be the top level directory in the zip file created.  I would like bar to be the top level directory.

Is there any easy way to go about this? I realize I could change directories before zipping to avoid the problem, but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't believe zip has a way to exclude the top level directory. I think your best bet would be to do something like:
pushd /foo; zip -r out.zip ./bar; popd;

But this is exactly the sort of answer you said you didn't want.

Comment: I doubt `tar -C /foo/bar -c out.tar *` makes him any happier.

Comment: I second this. I'm on a mac and need zip and not tar.gz. pushd seems like a really good alternative.

Answer (score 13):

This should do it:

```
cd /foo/bar/ 
zip -r ../out.zip *
```

The archive will be in `/foo/out.zip`

Comment: The OP said he doesn't want to change directories.

Comment: This answer does exactly what the OP wants.  Should've been the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm running zip in a PHP script. Now what?

Comment: If you don't want to change the directory of your "real" shell, [use a sub-shell](http://superuser.com/a/271992/229054).

Answer (score 6):

`7z a -tzip out.zip -w foo/bar/.`