# How to add files to zip archive without a intermediate folder

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, zip

I'm using `zip` program in a bash script and i would like to create an archive containing all files in a folder without adding the folder itself to the archive.

I have such files :

```
script.sh
files/
files/1
files/2
```

I'm using this command in script.sh

```
zip -q -9 -r arch.zip files/*
```

but this creates a `files` folder in the archive and i would like to get files `1` and `2` directly at the root of the archive.

How can i modify the parameters passed to `zip` command to prevent it from adding `files` in this archive ?

Thanks

FIXED :

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317928/how-to-zip-folder-without-full-path?rq=1) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710482/how-to-create-a-zip-file-without-entire-directory-structure?rq=1)

Obviously, SO search engine is more efficient when the question is posted than before ...

Comment: Once the question has been posted, you had already reflected on what your needs are exactly, then asking the machine (search engine) becomes straight-forward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cd files
zip -q -9 -r ../arch.zip *
```

Comment: so what your saying is: Folders get created relatively to the current path?

Comment: @luckydonald Exactly.

Answer (score 5):

you should use -j key. Try this way:

zip -q -9 -j arch.zip files/*

Comment: `-j` copy all files to the zip root. If you want subfolders this doesn't work.