# Zip folder contents from bash script

Tags: shell

I have a bash script which I use to zip everything in a folder called "distribution" which contains "file1" and "file2":

```
zip -r archive.zip distribution/*
```

However, when I open the zip file I see the entire "distribution" folder has been zipped. I just want to zip the files within the distribution folder and not the entire folder itself. How do I do this?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not general technical support questions.

Comment: There is the answer here [how-to-create-a-zip-file-without-entire-directory-structure][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710482/how-to-create-a-zip-file-without-entire-directory-structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go into the folder first:

```
cd distribution
zip -r ../archive.zip *
```

However, this means that when someone unzips it, the files will be put into their current folder, it won't put them into a subfolder.